# theano - use tensordot compute dot product of two tensor

Tags: numpy, theano, deep-learning

I want to use tensordot to compute the dot product of a specific dim of two tensors. Like:

A is a tensor, whose shape is (3, 4, 5)
B is a tensor, whose shape is (3, 5)

I want to do a dot use A's third dim and B's second dim, and get a output whose dims is (3, 4)

Like below:

```
for i in range(3):
    C[i] = dot(A[i], B[i])
```

How to do it by tensordot?

Comment: You seem to be wanting to multiply the third axis of B against the second of A, but you don't seem to want to keep all the combinations of that (that would be shape (3, 4, 3) and the result of tensordot). So you should probably indicate that you want the diagonal of the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, do you want this in numpy or in Theano? 
In the case, where, as you state, you would like to contract axis 3 of A against axis 2 of B, both are straightforward:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(3 * 4 * 5).reshape(3, 4, 5).astype('float32')
b = np.arange(3 * 5).reshape(3, 5).astype('float32')

result = a.dot(b.T)
```

in Theano this writes as

```
import theano.tensor as T

A = T.ftensor3()
B = T.fmatrix()

out = A.dot(B.T)

out.eval({A: a, B: b})
```

however, the output then is of shape (3, 4, 3). Since you seem to want an output of shape (3, 4), the numpy alternative uses einsum, like so

```
einsum_out = np.einsum('ijk, ik -> ij', a, b)
```

However, einsum does not exist in Theano. So the specific case here can be emulated as follows

```
out = (a * b[:, np.newaxis]).sum(2)
```

which can also be written in Theano

```
out = (A * B.dimshuffle(0, 'x', 1)).sum(2)
out.eval({A: a, B: b})
```

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, `einsum` is probably easier to understand than `tensordot`.  For example:

```
c = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', a, b)
```

I'm going to over-simplify the explanation a bit to make things more immediately understandable. We have two input arrays (separated by the comma) and this yields our output array (to the right of the `->`).

- `a` has shape `3, 4, 5` and we'll refer to it as `ijk`
- `b` has shape `3, 5` (`ik`)
- We want the output `c` to have shape `3, 4` (`ij`)

Seems a bit magical, right?  Let's break that down a bit.

- The letters we "lose" as we cross the `->` are axes that will be summed over.  That's what `dot` is doing, as well.
- We want output with shape `3, 4`, so we're eliminating `k`
- Therefore, the output `c` should be `ij`
- This means we'll refer to `b` as `ik`.

As a full example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((3, 4, 5))
b = np.random.random((3, 5))

# Looping through things
c1 = []
for i in range(3):
    c1.append(a[i].dot(b[i]))
c1 = np.array(c1)

# Using einsum instead
c2 = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', a, b)

assert np.allclose(c1, c2)
```

You can do this with `tensordot` as well.  I'll add an example of that as soon as I have a bit more time.  (Of course, if anyone else would like to add a `tensordot` example as another answer in the meantime, feel free!)

Comment: Thank you! And expect the tensordot version!