# Dot product with last two axises of two 3D arrays in numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, product, theano, dot-product

i try to do the dot product of two 3D numpy arrays.
Suppose i hava an array **x** with shape (2,3,2), the value is as follow:

```
array([[[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]],

      [[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1]]])
```

and i have another 3D array **y** , which shape is (2, 2, 3), and the value is :

```
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]]])
```

now i want to do the dot product of **x** and **y** at the last two axes.
i mean i would like to generate the results of

```
x[0].dot(y[0]) 
x[1].dot(y[1])
```

is there any simple method to do this ? i have already tried to use *x.dot(y)*, however, it did not work.
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used `tensordot` as much as `einsum`.  My first try calculates too many values, but I can filter those out:

```
In [388]: np.tensordot(x,y,(2,1))[[0,1],:,[0,1]]
Out[388]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2]]])
```

Come to think of it, that `tensordot` is the same as `np.dot(x,y)`, producing a (2,3,2,3) array.

```
In [389]: np.einsum('ijk,ikm->ijm',x,y)
Out[389]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2]]])

In [394]: x@y
Out[394]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 2, 2]]])
```

In `einsum` terms `dot` produces:

```
np.einsum('ijk,okm->ijom',x,y)
```

and then we have to remove the cases were `i!=o`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I will have a try!

Answer (score 5):

On NumPy 1.10 and up, this is

```
np.matmul(x, y)
```

If you're using at least NumPy 1.10 and Python 3.5, this can also be written as

```
x @ y
```

Comment: and `np.einsum('ijk,ikm->ijm',x,y)` on old numpy's.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, the problem is now i try to use it in theano(one of tools for deep learning), however, theano does not support einsum or matmul, i notice that "tensordot" is supported by both numpy and theano, but i do know how to solve it, could you give me some advice, a similar question is here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313460/theano-use-tensordot-compute-dot-product-of-two-tensor)

Comment: @LeiHua: If you wanted a Theano solution, you should have asked for one from the start. I've never used Theano, and I'm not familiar with how it works, so I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use Theano:

```
import theano
x = np.array([[[0,0],[1,1],[1,1]], [[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]])
y = np.array([[[0,0,0], [1,0,1]], [[0,1,1], [1,1,1]]])

res1 = theano.tensor.dot(x[0], y[0])
res2 = theano.tensor.dot(x[1], y[1])
```

Output:

```
In [36]: res1.eval()
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])

In [37]: res2.eval()
Out[37]: 
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 2]])
```