# How to put constraints on indexes involving different tensors in Theano?

Tags: python, theano

I want to multiply two big matrices and then to take only diagonal elements of the resulting matrix:

```
m1[i, j] = sum_k A[i, k] * B[k, j]
m2[i] = m1[i, i]
```

I can do it this way. However, doing it this way involves a lot of unnecessary operations. A better way to do it would be:

```
m[i, i] = sum_k A[i, k] * B[k, i]
```

Is there a way to "force" to do it the second way?

Comment: Is there any problem with do sum where `i == j` ?

Comment: @Arman, if i do it myself in a loop, there is no problems. However, I would like to use Theano commands (tensordot).

Comment: Do you mean `numpy.tensordot` ?

Comment: I mean `theano.tensordot`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313460/theano-use-tensordot-compute-dot-product-of-two-tensor

Comment: why not `T.sum(m1 * T.transpose(m2), axis=1)`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
T.sum(a * b.dimshuffle(1,0), axis = 1)
```

The explanation:

To "pair" indices of the first tensor with the indices of the second tensor we can use a pairwise multiplication. In this case all the dimensions of the first tensor will be paired with all the corresponding dimensions of the second tensor. However, to be able to do it we might need to reorder the dimensions since the i_th dimensions of the first tensor is always paired with i_th dimension of the second tensor. So, use transpose in the particular described cases.

After an element wise multiplication you can `sum` over some dimensions.